# Does QNetworkManager get accept compressed replies by default?

Tags: iis, qt, qt4, compression

I am using [QNetworkManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to fetch files from a server, however what I cannot figure out is if the files are compressed during the transfer with the standard gzip compression and if not how to get them to download compressed.

How would I go about checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran a quick test by adding:

```
request.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
```

to the QNetworkRequest and the data returns what look compressed (because its ~20% smaller and unusable).

It appears that the QNetworkManager and the QNetworkReply are not intelligent as far as decompression is concerned.  It looks like I have to implement a gzip and/or deflate on the returned QByteArray.

Comment: I finally found the solution to a problem that took a week of my life. I commented the line   request.setRawHeader ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate"); and finally was able to receive the soap message. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you set a custom `Accept-Encoding` raw header on a `QNetworkRequest` object (for example via an overridden `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` ), `QtWebKit` will never decompress the reply anymore: source code of `qhttpnetworkconnection.cpp` : ====================

```
    // If the request had a accept-encoding set, we better not mess
    // with it. If it was not set, we announce that we understand gzip
    // and remember this fact in request.d->autoDecompress so that
    // we can later decompress the HTTP reply if it has such an
    // encoding.
    value = request.headerField("accept-encoding");
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
#ifndef QT_NO_COMPRESS
        request.setHeaderField("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        request.d->autoDecompress = true;
#else
        // if zlib is not available set this to false always
        request.d->autoDecompress = false;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a packet sniffer / network analyzer and check for yourself.

QNetworkAccessManager does support receiving compressed HTTP replies, so in theory it should work if the HTTP server is correctly set up.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following sentence, I would say no, but they can be :

> The downloadProgress() signal is also
> emitted when data is received, but the
> number of bytes contained in it may
> not represent the actual bytes
> received, if any transformation is
> done to the contents (for example,
> decompressing and removing the
> protocol overhead).

You can find it here : https://doc.qt.io/qt/qnetworkreply.html

I didn't test it tho !

To compress, if I remember well, you can send QByteArray... And on this kind of objects, you can use "compress"...

You could also have a look at some Qt examples, like :

https://doc.qt.io/qt/qtnetwork-broadcastsender-example.html

I didn't look at all of them but maybe you'll find some interesting things !

Hope it helps a bit !

Answer (score 0):

Read this elsewhere so w/o having tested it: just don't set the accept-encoded header yourself, then QNam should handle it transparently (return decompressed payload).