# Read undecoded data from QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, http, gzip, qnetworkaccessmanager

Is it possible to read undecoded data from **QNetworkReply**?

Response is encoded using gzip (*Content-Encoding: gzip* HTTP header), but when i call **readAll()** method it returns decoded data. I need raw gzipped data, as it was sent to me. Any ideas?

Comment: Related to [does-qnetworkmanager-get-accept-compressed-replies-by-default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340548/does-qnetworkmanager-get-accept-compressed-replies-by-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set yourself the header for your `QNetworkRequest`:

```
 networkRequest.setRawHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
```

Then Qt doesn't decode for you in the reply.

We can see in the source of [qhttpnetworkconnection.cpp](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/network/access/qhttpnetworkconnection.cpp) for `QHttpNetworkConnectionPrivate::prepareRequest`:

```
    // If the request had a accept-encoding set, we better not mess
    // with it. If it was not set, we announce that we understand gzip
    // and remember this fact in request.d->autoDecompress so that
    // we can later decompress the HTTP reply if it has such an
    // encoding.
    value = request.headerField("accept-encoding");
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
#ifndef QT_NO_COMPRESS
        request.setHeaderField("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        request.d->autoDecompress = true;
#else
        // if zlib is not available set this to false always
        request.d->autoDecompress = false;
#endif
    }
```